# Oracle SQL function using Select Count returns duplicate answer for every row

Tags: sql, oracle, function, select, count

Trying to do a simple User function where I get the number of people whos age is > 100.

this is my current table

select * from peoples

```
**NAME**      **AGE**
----------------------
Joe Bloggs  12
Paul Smith  15
Jonah James 534
Mika Rive   31
Hannah Bananas  56
Harry Heelz 4
Brian Bolton    232
Jack Ripper 123
```

I'm currently trying to implement user function where the output is a single row with the total number of people with an age greater than 100.

Here is the function I have attempted to make

```
create or replace function agetest return number is
v_count number;

begin
    select count(age) into v_count
    from persons
    where  age > 100;
    
        return v_count;
end;
```

When I execute the SQL query directly I get the correct answer

```
select count(age) from persons where age > 100;
```

|  | COUNT(AGE) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |

but when I run the function

```
select agetest from persons;
```

I get the output of:

|  | AGETEST |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 3 |
| 7 | 3 |
| 8 | 3 |

Just looking for guidance on why the output is showing the same result for each row.

My ideal output for the function would just be:

|  | AGETEST |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |

Comment: Since you don't use a `WHERE` clause in your query, the result will be build for each row in your table. The fact you use a function doesn't matter because the query doesn't know what your function will do. Why do you want to use a function at all? This seems absolutely wrong to me. Just write a query and the job is done. If you want to use the function, try to select from the `dual` table rather than the `persons` table.

Comment: This is more of a build up to a larger question I have for school and I'm just trying to get the fundamentals down first.

Comment: Well, one of the most fundamentals things in my opinion is to prefer pure queries over functions or procedures. I often see people use them although not necessary. I think this makes things unnecessary complex because we don't directly see the query, but just the function or procedure call and need to check what is executed there. So I recommend to avoid functions and procedures if possible. But ok, that's just my point of view. Maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try executing the function against `DUAL`:

```sql
SELECT agetest FROM dual;
```

In Oracle, the `DUAL` table is a sort of dummy table which has only one record in it.

Comment: Nice side note: In Oracle 23c, we don't need to use the `dual` table anymore. We can just write `SELECT xy` without any `FROM` clause. As we can in any other RDBMS. This `dual` table is some very strange Oracle-thing and will become obsolete.

Comment: What I talk about is that we can write queries like `SELECT 1` without using a table or a `FROM` clause in common RDBMS. And now (or in future) we can also do it in Oracle and don't need the `dual` table.

Comment: @JonasMetzler, oops. I misread. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute the query:

```sql
select count(age) from persons where age > 100;
```

You aggregate all the rows into a single row.

When you do:

```sql
select agetest from persons;
```

You are not executing the first query because `agetest` is a scalar function (not an aggregation function) and you are effective executing:

```sql
SELECT (select count(age) from persons where age > 100) FROM persons;
```

Which is saying, for each row in `persons` execute the sub-query; which is why you get the function's return value repeated for each person and the output is:

| (SELECTCOUNT(AGE)FROMPERSONSWHEREAGE>100) |
| --- |
| 3 |
| 3 |
| 3 |
| 3 |
| 3 |
| 3 |
| 3 |
| 3 |

If you want to get the function value once then only execute it once by using a table that only has one row (such as `DUAL`):

```sql
SELECT agetest FROM dual;
```

Or, you can change the function from a scalar function to a user-defined aggregation function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CountGreaterThan100Type AS OBJECT(
  cnt NUMBER(10,0),

  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(
    ctx         IN OUT CountGreaterThan100Type
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(
    self        IN OUT CountGreaterThan100Type,
    value       IN     NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(
    self        IN OUT CountGreaterThan100Type,
    returnValue    OUT NUMBER,
    flags       IN     NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(
    self        IN OUT CountGreaterThan100Type,
    ctx         IN OUT CountGreaterThan100Type
  ) RETURN NUMBER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY CountGreaterThan100Type
IS
  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(
    ctx         IN OUT CountGreaterThan100Type
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    ctx := CountGreaterThan100Type( 0 );
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(
    self        IN OUT CountGreaterThan100Type,
    value       IN     NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    IF value > 100 THEN
      self.cnt := self.cnt + 1;
    END IF;
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(
    self        IN OUT CountGreaterThan100Type,
    returnValue    OUT NUMBER,
    flags       IN     NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    returnValue := self.cnt;
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(
    self        IN OUT CountGreaterThan100Type,
    ctx         IN OUT CountGreaterThan100Type
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    self.cnt := self.cnt + ctx.cnt;
    RETURN ODCIConst.SUCCESS;
  END;
END;
/

CREATE FUNCTION CountGreaterThan100( value NUMBER )
RETURN NUMBER
PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING CountGreaterThan100Type;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT CountGreaterThan100(age) FROM persons;
```

Outputs:

| COUNTGREATERTHAN100(AGE) |
| --- |
| 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Lr-TtcOa)